# Go's Buffered Channel's Blocking mechanism

Tags: go, channel

In the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/3), the sample code is given as such:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

It executed fine and printed out

```
1
2
```

This behavior is different from the description of this exercise, which stated:

> Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full. Receives block when the buffer is empty

after the line `ch <- 2`, `ch` is full, and since we are running only 1 single goroutine which is the main goroutine, this goroutine should be blocked until `ch` is consumed by a receiver, and thus the code should not reach the line of `fmt.Println(<-ch)`, but should says something like

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

However, as this was not the case, I am very confused, and look for guidance.

Here is another piece of code I wrote

```
chh := make(chan int, 2)

go func() {
    chh <- 1
    fmt.Printf("chh after 1: %v, %v\n", cap(chh), len(chh))
    chh <- 2
    fmt.Printf("chh after 2: %v, %v\n", cap(chh), len(chh))
    chh <- 3
    fmt.Printf("chh after 3: %v, %v\n", cap(chh), len(chh))
}()

fmt.Println(<-chh)
fmt.Println(<-chh)
fmt.Println(<-chh)
```

The result of the execution is

```
1
chh after 1: 2, 0
chh after 2: 2, 0
chh after 3: 2, 1
2
3
```

Which, is even more confusing. This time there is another goroutine doing the sending. My expectation is that, during first `fmt.Println(<-chh)`, main goroutine should be blocked. Scheduler will pick up the goroutine running anonymous function, and it should execute until `chh <- 2`, before it blocks itself and scheduler resume to the main goroutine again. However, as the result shown, the 2nd goroutine immediately blocked after `chh <- 1`. Why is that so?

**Edit**:
I still cannot figure out why my local printed 1 first. When I tried on go playground on remote server, it showed a difference behavior which is now align with my expectation.

Knowing channel is made up of 3 queues (receving goroutines, sending goroutines ans value buffer), when anonymous function runs, the state of the channel `chh` is `(sending: empty, value buffer: empty, receiving: [main])`.

The running child goroutine simply pushed the value straight into main goroutine, without actually passing it to value buffer. This is why the length of `chh` after pushed `1` was `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel has a capacity of two. Two sends can succeed without blocking. A *third* one cannot. A send only blocks if the channel was already full *before* the send.

Comment: I see, this seems like the correct explanation after some self testing. I do have another edit documented after my attempts in understanding, yet it showed a different behavior., are you able to take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

`ch` is a channel with capacity 2. It can hold at most 2 values, and when you attempt to put the 3rd value, it will block. The example puts only 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Here for above code what you are trying to do is creating a channel with capacity of 2 when you do

```
ch := make(chan int, 2)
```

below this code when you do

```
ch <- 1
```

it stores 1 in ch so now it has one value i.e. 1

```
ch <- 2
```

the above code stores second value i.e. 2, Here it has filled with its max capacity. Now if you have had tried with

```
ch <- 3
```

then it would have given you error instead you received the value from the channel by doing below statement

```
fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

The above statement removed 1 from ch and hence it printed 1. The second time you did same print statement it just simply removed 2 from ch hence ch variable at the end of execution didn't have anything. There is nothing confusing about it you can store values up to the capacity

```
ch <- value  // this syntax is for sending value kind of you can say storing value
<-ch // this syntax is for receiving value kind kind of popping value out of queue in FIFO manner
```

Comment: You did not understand the question. I am well aware of the syntax of how to send and receive, and I read the entire go101 on channel. I have explained why its confusing in the last paragraph, perhaps you can look at that.